# .htaccess redirecting equivalent to domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, dns

I have a host with a certain IP and I have two domains pointing at the same location. I want only one of the domains to be the one to represent my website, but the other one should be an alternative to access the website.

So lets say these are the domains:

- foo.com
- bar.net

**foo.com** is the main domain, while **bar.net** is the secondary domain. When I enter **bar.net**, my website will now be browsed as **bar.net** at the moment, as DNS records at my domain's configuration point to the same IP as **foo.com**. I want that changed... **bar.net** should still point to the main IP, but I thought of editing my website's `.htaccess` file and say that everything that comes from **bar.net**, should automatically redirect to **foo.com**.

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?bar\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://foo.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```